# .htaccess remove .php extension from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Here is the result i wanna to achieve:**

> http://www.sample.com/index.php?sec=fb&h=var2

to

> http://www.sample.com/fb?w=var1&var=2

**Here is the code from .htaccess file that i tried to use:**

```
RewriteRule ^fb$ fb.php [L]
```

I would really appreciate if someone taking their time to help me with this question. Many thanks!

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as PHP rewrite. If you want to remove the .php file extension, that can be done.

It's .htaccess rewrite, you could try using this on your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L, QSA]
```

Also, make sure that you've mod_rewrite on.

First step to do that, is open an SSH connection to your server, login with root and type

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

It will enable it for you, or tell that if it's already enabled.

And, make sure that file **000-default** located at **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled** has

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

instead of

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I need to correct my question: what i wanna achieve is:http://www.sample.com/index.php?sec=fb&=h=var2

to

http://www.sample.com/fb?w=var1&var=2

Comment: I can't help with that then, a bit too complicated for me. Why you even want to make a rewrite this complicated? @user2781144

Comment: Sorry if it made you laugh but i have always using this method to create my sites. i guess i will try to do it the way you suggested. Many thanks!

Comment: @user2781144 It's not SEO friendly, you should stick to clean URLS when possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve it for only one url which is 
http://www.sample.com/fb.php?w=var1&=h=var2

Then use below rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^fb /fb.php [L,QSA]
```

else if you want for every .php url,
Use the above answer by christian

your rewrite rule is fine, just add QSA at the end, to append the query string of the url

Comment: Thank you all, It worked after i added [L,QSA].

Comment: Great yr: if my answer helped you please accept it. :)

Comment: He never accepted the answer, @user2781144 ACCEPT IT:P

Comment: Add a $ after fb. `RewriteRule ^fb$ /fb.php [L,QSA]`